# Correct approach to test token expiration in PhpUnit

Tags: php, symfony, testing, caching, phpunit

I've written service for getting JWT token and caching it for 59 minutes. I'm writing now a tests for this service.
In my AuthService i have 2 methods:

```
public function getToken(): string
    {
        $token = $this->cache->getItem('access_token');
        // Czy jest token w cache
        if ($token->isHit()) {
            return $token->get();
        } else {
            $newToken = $this->getNewToken();
            $this->saveTokenInCache($newToken);
            return $newToken;
        }
    }

private function saveTokenInCache($tokenToSave): void
    {
        $savedToken = $this->cache->getItem('access_token');
        $savedToken->set($tokenToSave);
        $savedToken->expiresAfter(3540);
        $this->cache->save($savedToken);
   }
```

and I have a test:

```
 /**
     * @test
     */
    public function new_token_should_be_fetched_after_expiration()
    {
        $this->msGraphAuthService->expects($this->exactly(2))
            ->method('getNewToken');
        // getToken
        $this->msGraphAuthService->getToken();
        // change time
        $date = new DateTime();
        $date->modify('3541 seconds');
        $this->msGraphAuthService->getToken();

    }
```

For Cache I'm using `FileSystemAdapter`.

Setup Function with mock of `getNewToken` method is:

```
protected function setUp(): void
    {
        $kernel = self::bootKernel();
        $this->cacheService = new FilesystemAdapter();
        $this->serializer = $kernel->getContainer()->get('serializer');
        $this->logger = $this->createMock(Logger::class);
        $this->msGraphAuthService =$this>getMockBuilder(MicrosoftGraphAuthService::class)
            ->onlyMethods(['getNewToken'])
            ->setConstructorArgs([$this->logger, "", "", "", ""])
            ->getMock();
        $this->msGraphAuthService
            ->method('getNewToken')
            ->willReturn('{"token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3599,"ext_expires_in":3599,"access_token":"eyJ..."}');
    }
```

My exact goal in test **new_token_should_be_fetched_after_expiration** is to check if **getNewToken** method has been invoked exactly 2 times but how could I move time forward 59 minutes later than now?

I tried to do something like:

```
 $date = new DateTime();
 $date->modify('3541 seconds');
```

but it dosen't work.

I would be grateful for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like time is a hidden dependency of `getNewToken()`.

Make the dependency more visible. E.g. be it `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']` or a more dedicated `$date` parameter that defaults to it (or whatever you have in the implementation):

```
...
$date = new DateTime();
$token = $this->getNewToken($date);
...
```

You can then easily create tokens that expire soon, have expired already and/or you can remove the hidden dependency of time on the check routine as well.

Comment: I receive tokens from external API. Now I'm trying to use symfony timers mock: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/phpunit_bridge.html#time-sensitive-tests

Comment: If time is shared between two systems and you can not inject it, _and_ you want to test token expiration, you have to test ongoing, keep notes per tick and receive enough ticks. Then you can compare if the behaviour matches your expectation. E.g. `sleep()` etc. This is not a unit-test and belongs into a different suite. I would run this test double the time of the expected expiration time. Alternatively create a token in preparation that you know will be expired in the test and use it only for tests that expect an expiration (the fixture is the expired token). Again not strictly a unit-test.

Comment: I'm setting expiration time on my side like below:
  
        $savedToken = $this->cache->getItem('access_token');
        $savedToken->set($tokenToSave);
        $savedToken->expiresAfter(3540);
        $this->cache->save($savedToken);   That's not important to me whether it is unit test or not.

Comment: okay, then I've misread your comment. why don't you then test with an expire of a) -1 seconds, b) 0 seconds and c) 1 second? you can then process the results and find out if your initial expectations are reflected by the api.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately I have found solution:

```
    /**
     * @test
     *
     */
    public function new_token_should_be_fetched_again_after_expiration()
    {
        ClockMock::register(CacheItem::class);
        ClockMock::withClockMock(microtime(true) - 3600 * 24);
        // should be invoked exactly 2 times
        $this->msGraphAuthService->expects($this->exactly(2))
            ->method('getNewToken');
        // getToken
        $this->msGraphAuthService->getToken();
        $this->msGraphAuthService->getToken();
    }
```

Lines:

```
ClockMock::register(CacheItem::class);
ClockMock::withClockMock(microtime(true) - 3600 * 24);
```

cause that **CacheItem** class will invoke fake methods from [ClockMock](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/phpunit_bridge.html#clock-mocking). In second line I set up current time to time 24 hours ago. It causes that token is expired immediately.